# Ordenar vetor 2D em ordem decrescente

Tags: python, python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
a = [['UK', 'FR', **numero**], ['UK', 'NL', **numero**], ['UK', 'PT', **numero**]]
```

Onde a variável **numero** são valores ponto flutuante e diferentes.

Desejo ordenar os elementos do vetor de acordo com os valores da variável **numero**

Por exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte vetor e seus valores.

```
a = [['UK', 'FR', 0.021], ['UK', 'NL', 0.094], ['UK', 'PT', 0.034]]
```

Após a operação de ordenação, preciso que ele fique dessa forma:

```
a = [['UK', 'NL', 0.094], ['UK', 'PT', 0.034], ['UK', 'FR', 0.021]]
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método `sort` definindo o parâmetro `key`:

```
a.sort(key=lambda l: l[2], reverse=True)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FlawlessImpracticalUpgrades) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6lTTTf)</sup>

Assim, a lista `a` ficará ordenada levando em consideração o terceiro valor de cada lista (índice 2), de forma decrescente.

Comment: Exatamente o que precisava @Anderson Carlos Woss!

Novamente, muito obrigado.